# Is there any way to use a single for Loop for this code?

Tags: c++, performance, time-limit-exceeded

I want to use only one for Loop for this code. Is this possible? If not then how can I optimise my code further?

It works well for the constraint 1 ≤ T ≤ 10, 2 ≤ N ≤ 10^3, 1 ≤ M ≤ 10^5,
but I am getting time limit exceeded for 1 ≤ T ≤ 100, 2 ≤ N ≤ 10^5, 1 ≤ M ≤ 10^5.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);   

    cpp_int t,ans;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t-->0) {
    
        cpp_int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        
        cpp_int m;
        std::cin >> m;
        
        cpp_int count=0;
        
        for(int a=1;a<=n;++a) 
            {
                for(int b=1;b<=n;++b)
                {
                    
                    if(a<b) 
                     {
                       if( ((m%a)%b) == ((m%b)%a) )
                           count++;
                     }
            }
            }
            
            cout << count << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: This looks like a programming challenge, could you please include the text of the question and a link to the question?

Comment: [link](https://www.codechef.com/MAY21C/problems/MODEQ)

Comment: Do you need to use `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` or can you work with a regular integer type? The latter would likely be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the puzzle intends you to use more math and less brute force. But here's a 2x speedup right away: Any loop of the form

```
for (int a=1; a <= n; ++a)  {
    for (int b = 1; b <= n; ++b) {
        if (a < b) {
            do something
        }
    }
}
```

can obviously be replaced with a loop of the form

```
for (int a=1; a <= n; ++a)  {
    for (int b = a+1; b <= n; ++b) {
        assert(a < b);  // compile with -DNDEBUG for speed
        do something
    }
}
```

(Also, notice my indentation and whitespace style changes. Adopt them in all the code you write.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't write `using namespace std;`.  You certainly don't need to write it twice!!

`// your code goes here` along with the duplicated `using` declaration makes me think that you did not really proof-read your own code first.  Pay attention to what you're writing!  It will go a long way to finding improvements and silly mistakes.

`#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard header.  Some kind of implementation-specific header?  Or is it internal details you are not supposed to use directly?  Looking it up on Google, I see it's supposed to include all the standard headers... so why are you including others directly as well, and if it's supposed to be a precompiled header it needs to go first.  Again, it looks like you're just pasting things together and not understanding or reviewing what you wrote.

`cin.tie(NULL);`
Don't use the C macro `NULL`.  C++ has a keyword `nullptr` now.

`cpp_int t,ans;`
`ans` doesn't seem to be used anywhere, so why are you declaring it?  See comments above.  In general, don't define things ahead of their use, though the nature of `cin>>` I see why you are not initializing `t`.  Generally don't declare more than one thing at a time.

```
std::cin >> t;
    while(t-->0)
```

So you loop counting down `t` until it reaches 0.  You need `t` to be a arbitrary precision int because 64 bits isn't big enough??  If you are looping 2 to the 64 times, that would indeed take a long time.  That's 1.8e19, and if each iteration took one nanosecond that's still on the order of ten billion seconds, or 317 years.  So I seriously question your need to make `t` an extended precision integer and not a plain built-in 32-bit or 64-bit integer.

Likewise for `count` where you are counting up.  Does your program run for hundreds of years?  If not, 64 bit integers is enough!

Note for performance that `%` is a very slow operation.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [Quuxplusone's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260591/56343), let's get rid of some more operations.

```
for(int a = 1; a <= n; ++a)
{
    for(int b = a + 1; b <= n; ++b)
    {
        if( ((m%a)%b) == ((m%b)%a) )
            count++;
    }
}
```

One thing to notice is that the quantity `m%a` never changes during the inner loop. So, we can move it to the outer loop.

```
for(int a = 1; a <= n; ++a)
{
    int ma = m%a;
    for(int b = a + 1; b <= n; ++b)
    {
        if( (ma%b) == ((m%b)%a) )
            count++;
    }
}
```

The next transformation relies on two facts:

1. `x % y < y` for all positive integers `x` and `y`.
2. `x % y == x` for all positive integers `x` and `y` if `x` < `y`.

So, since `a < b`, `(m%a)%b == m%a`. This allows us to write `ma%b` as just `ma`.

```
for(int a = 1; a <= n; ++a) 
{
    int ma = m%a;
    for(int b = a + 1; b <= n; ++b)
    {
        if( ma == ((m%b)%a) )
            count++;
    }
}
```

Now, we've reduced the number of modulo operations by nearly half. This comes after the reducing by half in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But still time limit exceed is coming.

Comment: What happens if you replace `cpp_int` with `int`? None of the numbers are big enough to require an arbitrary-precision integer type.

Comment: @jerry00 See above question.